# Creating a wrapper for a react component

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and was wondering what it means to create a wrapper for a component. I have been trying to google this but no direct answer yet. Can any one assist me with what this implies and why would I want to create a wrapper for a component? Some sample code will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain the problem you're trying to solve first? "Wrapper" has many meanings depending on context.

Comment: The reason you would want to wrap a component is to provide props (as with a Redux provider) or to reduce the size of the file. A React component should only be about 2,000 lines long before you need to start wrapping things.

Comment: Be sure to check the answer if this is what you're looking for. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you place the component inside of another component — just like you would wrap any block-level element inside any other block-level `div` element.

### Unwrapped

```
    <Component1 {...props} />
```

### Wrapped

```
    <Component1Wrapper.div>
      <Component1 {...props} />
    </Component1Wrapper.div>
```

Sometimes you will need to pass props down from the Wrapper to the inner component (the "child").

### Wrapped (Provider)

```
    <Component1Provider comp1props={props} />
```

#### Inside Component1Provider

```
    <>
      {...other_components}
      <Component1 {...comp1props} />
    </>
```

Perhaps this documentation will help you understand a little better. If this is too complicated for your use case or if the concept is too complicated, don't hesitate to revisit the concept of a provider. It's a pattern that is used frequently in React, but it can also be sort of difficult sometimes, especially when you don't have a single "global provider" (sometimes called a "single source of truth").

https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider